# How to select everything apart from a div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page which I want to fade in/out. However, I don't want the menu (or anything in the div class `menu-outer`) to fade with it. I know hardly any jQuery, so was wondering if any of you know why this isn't working.

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body:not(div.menu-outer)').css('display', 'none');
    $('body:not(div.menu-outer)').fadeIn(1000);

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('body:not(div.menu-outer)').fadeOut(1000, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```

The html is huge so I wont post it, but the div I want to exclude has a class of menu-outer.

Comment: Can describe _"isn't working"_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 It fades everything on the page, including the menu, which I don't want to fade

Comment: _"The html is huge so I wont post it"_ Can post at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated, Note `$('body:not(div.menu-outer)').fadeOut(1000, newpage);` attaches callback `newpage` to every child element of `body` except for `div.menu-outer` ; would be called once for each element with the set; could utilize `.promise().done(fn)` as substitute ; to only call callback once

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function newpage(newLocation) {
      window.location = newLocation;
    }

    $('body *:not(div.menu-outer)').fadeOut(-3000);
    $('body *').fadeIn(1000);

    $('a').on("click", function (event) {
        var el = $(this);
        event.preventDefault();
        // newLocation = this.href;
        $('body *:not(div.menu-outer)').fadeOut(1000)
         .promise().done(function() {
            // do other stuff
            newpage(el.attr("href"))
          });

    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g8sdc5q6/2/

Comment: This still fades everything on the page for some reason

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working in my code. The menu-outer div contains many other divs and elements, which may be why?

Comment: Not certain , difficult to determine without `html` included at Question ? What is _"still isn't working"_ ? Does jsfiddle fade out elements there as expected ? Try adding elements to jsfiddle , one or two at a time -  within `div.menu-outer` -  until find which elements are not fading in , out as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('*').not("div.menu-outer").fadeOut();
```

This tells that: select everything: `$(*)`, except `div.menu-outer`: `.not("div.menu-outer")`

Comment: Things inside the div still fade in/out with the page

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the menu's ancestor elements, which in turn hides the menu. You can try something like this:

```
var menuParents = $('div.menu-outer').parents();
$('*').not('div.menu-outer').not(parents).css('display', 'none');
$('*').not('div.menu-outer').not(parents).fadeIn(1000);
```